# How strong are eddy current brakes?

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid

I really just need a rough estimation. How strong are eddy current brakes? For example, if I use a solenoid that has 800 turns with up to 2 amps going through it, and I have the not ferromagnetic metal going through the middle of the solenoid, how powerful would the eddy current braking effect be? I just need to know if I should look deeper into this concept for my experiment, which requires something to act as a damper for a small spring-mass system.

Comment: In contrast to purely mechanical brakes eddy current brakes work only if there is motion. I.e. braking force depends not only on the magnetic field but also on the speed of the conductor moved through the field. They don't brake at all if everything is at rest; no matter how strong the field is (that's why they often are ideal for dampening). Therefore your question is missing essential information: the speed of the conductor (and other mechanical/geometrical details) required to give a quantitative answer.

Comment: If you place a strong neodymium disc magnet on a nearly vertical aluminum surface that is at least as thick as the magnet it will slide slowly down the surface compared the time it would take if the surface is wood or plastic.

Comment: Great experiment: a magnet goes through three pipes: plastic, metal, copper. It takes significant longer to come through the copper pipe. Metal is second, plastic is first.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I see that I forgot to mention the speed of the conductor. It is not too high, I would say it would not exceed 1 m/s. If I forgot to mention any further information, just make it up, I am looking for estimates anyway, I dont have anything super accurate in mind yet.

Comment: Eddy current brakes are used on trucks, buses and coaches and they can slow down 40 or 60 tons...

Comment: Eddy current brakes are great for braking at "higher" speed even if large masses have to be decelerated because they have no wear (no mechanical friction involved!). They are completely useless at slow speeds or rest (as fixing brakes).

Comment: Ampere turns per meter is important. Which makes me wonder, given you are looking for quantitative answers, why it may be that no one has asked you about the length of your solenoid. (The conductive material matters too. And so do things like holes you might cut in it. So geometries and shape modifications have immediate impact on the eddy currents that are possible.)

Comment: Your design is great. It'll work. You MUST try it downhill though....  please  ?

Answer (score 0):

Experiment:

Neodymium magnet disc: 30mm dia, 5mm thick, about 40 grams

Aluminum Bar: 920mm long, 40mm wide, 3mm thick

Leaning against a wall, 80mm space at bottom

Time to slide from top to floor: about 4 seconds (stopwatch, but old operator)

Note that there is no air gap, so some friction.

[image]

Comment: My favorite trick is to drop a cylindrical magnet down an aluminum tube.  Everyone expects it to drop right out the bottom.  In fact, it takes several seconds to pass through - even when the tube is vertical.

Comment: Copper pipe also works for the tube. A good demonstration is to mount the pipe vertically with the bottom several inches off the ground and drop different items through it and next to it. Use non-magnetic balls (e.g., lead ball, ball bearing, marble) in addition to the magnet and drop 2 items simultaneously, one through the pipe and the other outside the pipe. The long travel time of the magnet through the pipe is remarkable in comparison to the free fall of the other item.

Comment: A demonstration sequence is to ask an audience if two items, if dropped at the same time should hit the floor at the same time. Ask if dropping one through the pipe would make a difference. Drop the non-magnetic item through the pipe and the magnet outside. They will reach the floor at the same time. Then drop the magnet through the pipe and the other item outside the pipe. This is the opening to explain eddy currents and how the principle is used on roller coasters as safety brakes. This was a fun demonstration for Cub Scouts.

Answer (score 0):

Beware: you asked for one thing, but say you need another.  I will answer the first, then explain why it doesn't provide the second.

"Strength" generally means force.

Maximum possible strength basically comes down to flux density at the surface of the magnet, including magnetization from the magnet itself and any contributions from pole pieces; and the cross-sectional area being interacted with.  A wider face at the same flux density makes more force; more flux density at the same face area makes more force.

You make it bigger, you make it more powerful, it becomes stronger.  Makes sense.

We can express this as the Maxwell stress, \$\sigma = \frac{B^2}{2 \mu_0}\$, which is both a pressure (force per area: multiply by area to get total force) and an energy density (integrated over the magnetic field volume, the energy stored in the magnetic field).

The energy storage is important when driving it by a winding: how much power you need to apply to a resistive winding to maintain it, or energy applied to a superconducting winding to arrive there.

Flux density is normally limited to around 1.5T, the maximum available from NdFeB magnets, the maximum that silicon steel pole pieces can support (saturation), etc.  The corresponding pressure is comparable to, say, average vehicle tire pressure -- and so, give or take coefficient of friction, comparable braking force per area.

Higher flux density is possible with nonmagnetic materials, whether with good conductors for short duration (lest they heat up and melt, or if extraordinarily good cooling is provided), or with superconductors (in which case, cryogenic rather than water cooling is required).

We can't make use of the 800t at 2A figure, as we don't know the core area or length, how much energy is being stored in it: it could be a coil all 'round the Earth, or something the size of a nickel (say for pulsed operation, or using superconductors).  The former might not be very practical at this time, or the latter rather esoteric, but hey, thought experiments are fun, and I can't assume any particular case.  This is why it is best to include concrete examples when writing a question.

As for research; you may find this of interest: 
[L. Rudolfsen, "Modeling and control of eddy-current brakes", Project Thesis, NTNU, 2018](https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2625764/no.ntnu:inspera:2471439.zip?sequence=7) 
which curiously is a zipped PDF download for some reason, but, it appears safe to open.  It also appears on Studocu: 
https://www.studocu.com/in/document/birla-institute-of-technology-and-science-pilani/computational-fluid-dynamics/project-thesis-lars-rudolfsen/31771244 
Lars' other paper looks interesting too (direct PDF link): 
[L. Rudolfsen, "Numerical Realization of Fractional Eddy Current Dynamics", Master's Thesis, NTNU, 2019](https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2625764/no.ntnu:inspera:2471439.pdf?sequence=6)

In fact it's even more interesting than the above, because force reaches a peak (p. 9-10), and then declines inversely proportionally from there.  This can be seen as something like: the sheet is moving so fast past the magnets that the induced current ("trapped field") moves away from the magnet so fast that it sees less flux density, and for less time.

---

The reason this doesn't provide for the second (you wanted to know damping factor), is because the maximum force is only mildly related to the damping factor.  There are other variables in play, and we could for example vary them in such a way that a constant force/velocity slope is had, yet the peak force and critical velocity vary widely.

Though you may find this paper answers both questions, after all.

Finally, a comment on geometry: a solenoidal geometry isn't very common (if used at all?), as the material thickness isn't very well controlled (it's a rod of given thickness, not a sheet of variable thickness and area), only the fringing field acts across the rod to provide braking force, and the magnet's size is limited by the rod within.

A more typical implementation would be to flatten the rod, or attach fins to it in any case, and place those fins within a magnetic field.  The fin thickness and area can be adjusted freely, as can the magnetic field area and air gap.  The magnet can be optimized with high flux density right at the fins, without depending on fringing fields.  Any other forces on the rod, don't need to be carried by the fins, but can proceed along its length regardless -- whereas in the direct solenoid case, minimum rod size is determined by the force through it.  (And perhaps maximum rod size is determined by permissible mass in the system, say if it needs to be designed with a high natural/resonant frequency.)

This scheme also allows the use of magnetic or nonconductive materials for the mechanical parts, and nonmagnetic metals (preferably aluminum or copper) for the fins.